# How can I resolve gstreamer dependencies in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-8.04, gstreamer

Can you please tell me how can I resolve these dependencies on ubuntu:

```
checking for GSTREAMER... configure: error: Package requirements (gstreamer-0.10 >= 0.10
                     gstreamer-app-0.10
                     gstreamer-base-0.10
                     gstreamer-pbutils-0.10
                     gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10 >= 0.10.25
                     gstreamer-video-0.10) were not met:

No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
No package 'gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10' found
No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
```

I have tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install *gstreamer-video*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Regex compilation error - Invalid preceding regular expression
$ sudo apt-get install *gstreamer-app*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Regex compilation error - Invalid preceding regular expression
$ sudo apt-get install *gstreamer-base*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Regex compilation error - Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Answer (score 56):

```
$ apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

which you could have found by doing a search for `gstreamer-app-0.10.pc` in package contents on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) or with `apt-file search`, or by running the whole configuration process within `auto-apt run`.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This also worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10 and your answer should be marked as the correct one.

Comment: This worked for me on debian! :)

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: This worked for me Ubuntu 16.04 :)

Comment: no longer works with ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 19.04 :(

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
apt-get install libgstreamer*
```

Comment: Thanks . I tried that. But still same error.  I have tried '$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer*-dev' but it does not work.

Comment: Tried this too, but cant install or find decklinksrc

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that '$ apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev'

But it now said:

```
Requested 'gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10 >= 0.10.25' but version of GStreamer Base Plugins Libraries is 0.10.18
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GSTREAMER_CFLAGS
and GSTREAMER_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

So download and 'make install' gstreamer in /home/michael/bin (./configure --prefix-/home/michael/bin).

And the I have set

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/home/novarra/bin/lib/pkgconfig
$ echo $GSTREAMER_LIBS
/home/scheung/bin/lib/pkconfig
```

And rerun ./autogen.sh --enable-debug

I set get the same 'Requested 'gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10 >= 0.10.25' but version of GStreamer Base Plugins Libraries is 0.10.18'

Comment: michael, you need to associate your accounts in your user profile (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon).  then you'll regain ownership of this question.

Answer (score 1):

`libgstreamer0.10-dev` doesnt seems to work in Ubuntu 18/19 but I tried the 1.0 version like this:

```
sudo apt install -y libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

Just in case anyone needs to know